# Microsoft sync framework slow for tables without identity field (and composite primary key)

Tags: azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework, composite-primary-key

I'm using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 to do a one-way replication from our on-premises database to an Azure Sql Database. When syncing tables that don't have an identity field and a composite primary key, sync is running 4 sql statements for every row in all of these tables.

```
UPDATE [MYTABLE_tracking] SET [update_scope_local_id] = @sync_scope_local_id, [scope_update_peer_key] = @sync_update_peer_key, [scope_update_peer_timestamp] = @sync_update_peer_timestamp, [local_update_peer_key] = 0, [local_update_peer_timestamp] = @nextRowVersion, [sync_row_is_tombstone] = @sync_row_is_tombstone WHERE ([PrimaryCol1] = @P_1 AND [PrimaryCol2] = @P_2) AND (@sync_check_concurrency = 0 or [local_update_peer_timestamp] = @sync_row_timestamp)

SELECT [side].[PrimaryCol1], [side].[PrimaryCol2], ... , [side].[sync_row_is_tombstone], [side].[local_update_peer_timestamp] as sync_row_timestamp, case when ([side].[update_scope_local_id] is null or [side].[update_scope_local_id] <> @sync_scope_local_id) then [side].[local_update_peer_timestamp] else [side].[scope_update_peer_timestamp] end as sync_update_peer_timestamp, case when ([side].[update_scope_local_id] is null or [side].[update_scope_local_id] <> @sync_scope_local_id) then case when ([side].[local_update_peer_key] > @sync_scope_restore_count) then @sync_scope_restore_count else [side].[local_update_peer_key] end else [side].[scope_update_peer_key] end as sync_update_peer_key, case when ([side].[create_scope_local_id] is null or [side].[create_scope_local_id] <> @sync_scope_local_id) then [side].[local_create_peer_timestamp] else [side].[scope_create_peer_timestamp] end as sync_create_peer_timestamp, case when ([side].[create_scope_local_id] is null or [side].[create_scope_local_id] <> @sync_scope_local_id) then case when ([side].[local_create_peer_key] > @sync_scope_restore_count) then @sync_scope_restore_count else [side].[local_create_peer_key] end else [side].[scope_create_peer_key] end as sync_create_peer_key from [MYTABLE] [base] right join [MYTABLE_tracking] [side] on [base].[PrimaryCol1] = [side].[PrimaryCol1] and [base].[PrimaryCol2] = [side].[PrimaryCol2] WHERE [side].[PrimaryCol1] = @P_1 AND [side].[PrimaryCol2] = @P_2

SELECT @was_tombstone = [sync_row_is_tombstone] FROM [MYTABLE_tracking] WHERE ([PrimaryCol1] = @P_1 AND [PrimaryCol2] = @P_2)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MYTABLE_tracking] WHERE [PrimaryCol1] = @P_1 AND [PrimaryCol2] = @P_2)
```

A lot of these tables are many-to-many tables. Some have an identity field but Sync Framework doesn't support scenarios where the identity is other that the primary key so I had to exclude the identity column from sync. Before my database is synced I get a million database queries which slows sync down so it takes more than 24 hours to sync and my Azure bill is also growing.

Can I somehow instruct Sync framework when provisioning these tables so it can optimize sync?

The target database is read-only, i.e. only the sync writes to it so I can remove constraints etc. I have created the database without foreign keys but would it help if I created the target database also without primary keys?

UPDATE:
If I create the target database without indexes I get the error

> Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncException: Failed to execute the
>   command 'BulkInsertCommand' for table 'CNT_ContentNode'; the
>   transaction was rolled back. Ensure that the command syntax is
>   correct. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Tables without a
>   clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server.
>   Please create a clustered index and try again.

-Mathias

Comment: are you seeing conflicts being fired? can you enable syncfx tracing and see what it says about conflicts or errors?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing all primary keys from tables with composite keys and replacing them with clustered unqiue indexes in stead. Now it's working properly.

-Mathias